# Tint custom image in UIBarButton Item

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

To animate the image in a `UIBarButton` Item, I've created two regular `UIButtons`, button1 and button2 with different images, image1 and image2 and assign them to the UIBarButtonItem's customView property with:

```
self.myBarButton.customView = button1;
```

I am able to do the animation by assigning one or the other buttons to the `UIBarButtonItem`.

My problem is the first image is a line drawing that I want to tint.  The second is a full color image that I don't want to tint. For some reason, if I set the rendering mode of the first image to `UIImageRenderingModeTemplate` which allows it to tint, then the second image does not display even if I set the rendering mode of the second to `UIImageRenderingModeAlways`.

Is there any way to tint the image that does not involve changing the rendering mode.  I do have the line `[button1 setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]`; but it has no effect.

Also can anyone explain why setting the rendering mode would prevent the second image from appearing?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Show relevant code.

Comment: What you're doing is really not supported; you cannot change a UIBarButtonItem's `customView` after it has appeared in the interface.

Comment: Is that the sort of thing that App store would flag?